# Dropdown button inside Alert component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I've been searching how to embed a dropdown button inside the Alert component antd. I took it simple, just to add a button inside the Alert such as is shown in the documentation:

[image]

However, when copying the same code in my React project, the button is not present in the alert and no errors shown in the console. The code looks like this:

UserAlert.js:

```
export const UserAlert = () => (
    <>
        <Alert
            message="Success Tips"
            type="success"
            showIcon
            action={
                <Button size="small" type="text">
                    UNDO
                </Button>
            }
            closable
        />
        <Alert
            message="Error Text"
            showIcon
            description="Error Description Error Description Error Description Error Description"
            type="error"
            action={
                <Button size="small" danger>
                    Detail
                </Button>
            }
        />
    </>
);
```

which is invoked from a parent component called UserSummary.js:

```
export class UserSummary extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <UserAlert/>
    )};
}

export default UserSummary;
```

The previous code is not failing, but showing like this:
[image]

Am I missing something? Should I try in different way?

Thanks a lot for you attention and help.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce it, but for me the button appears. And one thing that's wrong in your snippet is the name of the Alert component. It's called MineAlert, but in the UserSummary, you use UserAlert. I think it's just a typo?

I tried it here:
https://codesandbox.io/embed/vigorous-rain-j6y1oj?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Maybe some information about the imports and styling you use would be helpful. Would be great if you could share a bit more context.